# Add Images to GridViews (Android)

Tags: android

I have script that loads images from url using AsynkTasc. Now, i need dynamically ADD (not reload or other) images **to already existing images when the user scrolls down, like in android market.** I dont have any idea. I try notifyDataSetChanged, but as I know its refresh. But i need ADD. Please tell me what can i do ?

When I try setadapter settings, its just reload. Have GridView something like "AddToAdapter" :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: I know about LazyList, and I use it in my script. It is not useful for  this project. Because if i have 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 rows in my DB all they will downloaded. But I need djwnload ONLY 10 images and ADD to already downloaded images, then when user scroll down again 10 will downloaded and ADDed. If user not scroll down, then NOT downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

After your images are downloaded, you have to call notifyDataSetChanged, and then your adapter will have to regenerate views, taking into account the new data.

Comment: I know...so my question is how take it INTO.

Comment: It depends. You write the adapter, so you're responsible for managing the new data (i.e it's not automagic). Show us your adapter.

Comment: Thanks. I just use Adapter which extends BaseAdapter. with getCount(), getView and etc.

Comment: Please paste your adapter if you want more help

Comment: Thanks, but i dont think if i paste adapter, it something change, and someone can help me. So I find my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement LoaderCallbacks interface in your GridView implementation.

You can find an [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LoaderThrottle.html) for ListViews in android developer website.